# Cloning DIV with new values using Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a web application where users can add Notes, there is a form and when a user presses the Add button, then new note div should be created with added noted.
There is already a div populated with values using PHP, but this notes are visible when users refresh page.

I can successfully add notes in DB when Add button press, but I see that note only after refresh of page, because PHP function will show that,

What I want is then when note added, it just adds new div in notes,

Below is my HTML code,

```
<?php
    foreach($testingnotes_array as $testingnote)
    {
    ?>

    <div id="testingnoteappend">
        <div id="testingnoteclone">
            <div class="todo-tasklist-item todo-tasklist-item-border-red" id="testingnotebox<?php echo $testingnote['thread_id'];?>">
                <img class="todo-userpic pull-left" src="<?php echo base_url().'/uploads/dp/'.$testingnote['user_profiledp'];?>" width="28px" height="28px">
                <div class="todo-tasklist-item-title">
                    <?php echo $testingnote['user_firstname']." ".$testingnote['user_lastname'];?>
                    <span class="todo-tasklist-date">
                        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                        <?php echo date($datetimesetting->ss_datetimeformat, strtotime($testingnote['threadcreated_time']));?>
                    </span>
                    <a href="javascript:removetestingnote<?php echo $testingnote['thread_id'];?>();">
                        <i class="fa fa-trash-o pull-right"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>                                              
                <div class="todo-tasklist-item-text">
                    <?php echo $testingnote['testingbody'];?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php
     }
?>
```

Below is my JS,

```
$("#testingnotes_fm").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/phase/testings/addtestingnotes/"+<?php echo $testinginfo->testing_id; ?>,
    data: $("#testingnotes_fm").serialize(),
    success: function(data) 
    {
        $( "#testingnoteclone" ).clone().appendTo( "#testingnoteappend" );
    }   
});
});
```

With above code, I can see cloning of my existing note, but I want cloning of div structure but with new values from DB,

I can get JSON values back from server,

Can you help how I can add new note without reloading page + new data?

Comment: You are generating duplicate IDs with the PHP shown. That is invalid HTML for starters and jQuery/Javascript will not work with any other IDs except the *first* match.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie, that can be solved by putting that two IDs outside of PHP loop, but how can i add new note div with new values?

Comment: Good timing: suggestions added below.

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to write this for you (as I dislike PHP on many levels and you need to rework it a lot), but here are a number of suggestions on how you *could* approach the problem.

Cloning an existing entry is often error prone, so the following shows one way of using a single empty template. You should find this approach is easier to read and maintain:

1. Get your notes via Ajax and JSON data. This will reduce the use of bandwidth (compared to injecting the formatted results into the page directly.
2. Suggestion: *Always* get your notes via Ajax (even on the first call). This makes the initial page load more responsive and means only one set of code required for producing notes.
3. Keep an empty template in the page to use for the notes. e.g. store it in a dummy script block with `type="text/template"` (which is then ignored by browsers).
4. Access the template with `$('#notetemplate').html()` or similar.
5. Replace markers in the template text with the relevant data fields.
6. Never use hard-wired IDs in repeated data. Duplicate IDs are invalid HTML and jQuery/Javascript can only see the first match.
7. On initial load, fetch all relevant notes via Ajax and display by repeatedly using the code you will use for a single note.
8. Use `data-` attributes to inject values for client-side code use. e.g. `{{threadid}}` in the example below.

Sample template (using moustache-style markers):

```
<script id="notetemplate" type="text/template">
    <div>
        <div class="todo-tasklist-item todo-tasklist-item-border-red" data-threadid="{{threadid}}">
            <img class="todo-userpic pull-left" src="{{profileurl}}" width="28px" height="28px">
            <div class="todo-tasklist-item-title">{{firstname}} {{lastname}}<span class="todo-tasklist-date">
                        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                        {{date}}
                    </span>
 <a href="{{removealurl}};">
                        <i class="fa fa-trash-o pull-right"></i>
                    </a>

            </div>
            <div class="todo-tasklist-item-text">{{testingbody}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

9. Come back here with a new question once you have tried all this :)

Comment: thanks you, i am almost near to my solution, just let me know how to replace markers with my values which i got from JSON?

Comment: @rjcode: If there is only one of each in the template, just use `html = html.replace("{{threadid}}", jsondata.threadId)` etc If there were multiples in the template you need to use a RegEx like `/{{threadid}}/gi` instead of `"{{threadid}}"`

Comment: Thanks, now i had did it in different way, i did put my html in PHP controller and adding values whenever it called and echoing JSON with my html, this JSON will include my new data values as well and then in HTML AJAX, i simply did prepend to put that div, it worked better, thanks,

Comment: @rjcode; That does exactly what I suggested you should *not* do: i.e. bloat the bandwidth with unnecessary HTML. *sigh*. :(